# Chess table Mathematical Induction Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

You have a chess table of size $n\times n$ , give a proof that this table can be covered using trominos if a square of size $1\times 1$ has been removed only if $n$ is odd, isn't divisible by 3, and $n>5$.

In case you forgot this is how a tromino looks like:

[image]

I gave my own proof, by first proving that we can construct such a table if $n=7$, so $P(7)$ came true, then i used the induction hypothesis on $n$ then attempted to prove for $n+1$ by separating this newly created table and showing that the inductive hypothesis holds if we remove 2 squares in separate square-sections so I came to the conclusion that $P(n+1)$ is true (holds for $n$-odd, non divisible by 3).

Have I missed anything in my proof, could it be wrong are there other solutions?

Comment: But if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ must not be true. What you need to prove is $P(n+6)$ being true.

Comment: We know that n has to be n>5 so any n+1 where n is odd and non divisible by 3, is merely accepting of the first qualifications

Comment: When $n$ is odd $n+1$ must be even, so $P(n+1)$ must not be true.

Comment: I understand that but we show that P (n+1) is true when n meets all requirements stated above and we do not specify a specific value say 5 such that 5+1 be 6 and then that be even and incorrect we move on to 7 since that would be next after 6 that does achieve all requirements, in terms of n it would have to be n+1

Comment: When you prove by induction, you need to make sure if the precious case is true then the next case is true. You cannot have something false in between. In terms of this question, when you first show $7$ is true, the next true value is $13$ and you cannot say $7$ is true and $8$ is not true and $9,10,11,12$ is not true and suddenly  $13$ is true. That does not logically make sense.

Comment: Are you sure the question says "only if" instead of "if"?

Comment: @Git Gud. It looks like once the "odd" condition is eliminated then the statement is an "if and only if" with the exception of $n=4$

Comment: In induction, $n+1$ **does not mean** “the next number that satisfies the conditions.” It means exactly what it says: it is a number exactly $1$ unit greater than $n.$ If $n$ is odd then $n+1$ is even regardless of what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Also, your proof (if it works after fixing technical details such as the use of $n$ and $n+1$ in your formulas) would prove a version of the statement in which the words “only if” are changed to “if”. In fact the “only if” statement is false, as shown below.

Comment: Okay so the last statement to be proven is P (n+6)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a counter example for $10\times10$ (Generally $6k+4$) so the claim is actually wrong.

[image]

Edit: also found examples for $6k+2, 6k+7, 6k+11$ so essentially as long as $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ it will work.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit2: In fact $n=5$ works as well so we don't even need the $n>5$ condition. Essentially every $n$ not divisible by $3$ will work.

[image]

Comment: Nice Paint skills.

Comment: I was going to replace your first diagram when the answer had only one diagram. But since you added a lot more, I elected not do it. I was doing in on Excel, [here](https://ufile.io/1bpkc)'s the file, if anyone wants to go through the trouble. It should be available for one month before it is autodeleted.

Comment: So the standart final solution is that it is false?

Comment: @Danny_007 That's right. If the original question says "If" instead of "Only if" then it would be true but you need to show both $n=7$ and $n=11$ base cases and pad $+6$ each time for induction.

Comment: Also 10 is even and not odd

Comment: Thanks for your solution, am going through your solution right now, (felt i should say thanks!)

Comment: @Danny_007 That's why this is a counter-example to the statement.

Comment: See the way i solved this problem i think is correct except i should have said P(n+6) instead of my mistake P(n+1),  what you did in your solution if i understood it well enough is proof that for n-odd where n>5 and non divisible by 3 then the statement holds (as in your graphical answers, thanks again), after that what i did in my own answer is that i assume by induction hypothesis that it holds for n (with labeled conditions) then showed that if we had a big chess table of size "now"  (n+6)*(n+6) then we could seperate the big square into 4 subsquares and remove one square from each, that...

Comment: ...would show each subsquare (table in itselfe) could be covered by trominos if the all had met the first conditions by the induction hypothesis, however i am unsure if we would need to remove 4 squares or more or maybe more subsquares , but it would probably be just 4 squares if we had 4 sub squares

Comment: @Danny_007 Yes that would be the correct way. And it is fairly easy to cover $6\times x$ for any $x\geq 2$ with $2\times 3$ rectangles. However be careful there are $4$ base cases instead of one, as shown in my solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, do you know how you would have to go forward in the last part where we prove for P(n+6) would you say that what i did where i seperated the chesstable into 4 sub sections then used the inductive hypothesis would be correct?

Comment: The idea is right. Actually you need only three sub sections. The original $n\times n$, one $6\times(n+6)$ rectangle and another $n\times 6$ rectangle. When $n$ is even just fill with $2\times 3$ rectangles with same orientation. When $n$ is odd fill the first three rows with three $3\times 2$ rectangles and the remaining $2\times 3$.

Comment: @Danny_007 Please consider accepting this answer and, if you have an account, upvote it.

Comment: Yeah will do right now, sorry if a bit clumsy i'm new to this :)

Comment: Also i could not vote up since i need to still build up some reputation